# Sorting two list simultaneously but not with selection sort

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, indexing, unique

I  have a list of some random values and another list of same length with corresponding indices. I want to sort the first list and in the second list the indices should be sorted along the values in the first list. I was able to achieve it but I when the number repeats it doesn't give the unique index for it. 
here's my code

```
some_list = [4,8,6,1,1,3]
index = [(1,1),(1,6),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5)]
new_index_pos = index.copy()
randomm = []
b = some_list.copy()
b.sort()

for i in range(len(b)):
    node = b[i]
    my_index = some_list.index(node)
    new_index_pos[i] = my_index
    val = new_index_pos[i]
    randomm.append(index[val])
```

the output i'm getting is :
b = [1, 1, 3, 4, 6, 8]  and randomm = [(1, 3), (1, 3), (1, 5), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 6)]. 
how do i solve this issue?
This is a sample list and values can be repeated more than two times

Comment: whats your expected output

Comment: this is my original index list alongside some_list    [(1,1),(1,6),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5)]

Comment: this also gets sorted with some_list but instead of (1,3) , (1,3) i want (1,3) and (1,4)

Comment: the index method of a list states `Return first index of value.` so when you search for `1` in some_list usig index you will always get the first value unless you pass in from which index to start from to search after

Answer (score 0):

You can just zip the lists together then sort them and then take the tuple values.

```py
some_list = [4,8,6,1,1,3]
index = [(1,1),(1,6),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5)]
new_list = [i[1] for i in sorted(zip(some_list, index))]
print(new_list)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 6)]
```